# kotlin 1.1.4 primitives in generic class

Tags: android, kotlin

I declare a field like this in an object class:

```
private val longObjectResourceDecoder = object : ResourceDecoder<Long, Any> {}
```

Then I got this java code generated into stub java class by kapt:

```
private static final com.bumptech.glide.load.ResourceDecoder<long, java.lang.Object> longObjectResourceDecoder = null
```

It won't compile because the primitive type `long` is used as the type parameter!

**I've tried:**

1. Clean & Build
2. Configure kotlin update to 1.1.4 in Android Studio

But the problem still exists. How can I solve this?

Comment: I've reported a bug for this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19750

Comment: Good to know I'm not alone here ^_^